# Files gets uploaded sometimes and fails most of the time getting error SFTP with key file using SSH.NET (Permission denied (publickey))

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp

I am trying to upload file using SFTP. The file gets uploaded sometimes and most the times it throws the error **SSH.NET (Permission denied (publickey))** The SFTP server accepts only whitelist IP addresses.

Locally the application works fine.

Using SSH.NET 2016.1.0

**Code**

```
public void SetConnection(string userName, string strRSAKey)
        {
            var authMethods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
            authMethods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(
                userName, 
                new[] { new PrivateKeyFile(GenerateStream(strRSAKey)) }
                ));

            connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(hostName, port, userName, authMethods.ToArray());
        }

        public bool UploadFile(string sourceFilePath, string destinationFilePath)
        {
            if (connectionInfo != null)
            {
                using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
                {
                    client.Connect();
                    if (client.IsConnected)
                    {
                        var csvFile = File.Open(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open);
                        client.UploadFile(csvFile, destinationFilePath, true);
                        csvFile.Dispose();
                    }
                    client.Disconnect();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private Stream GenerateStream(string str)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(str);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
```

Comment: This seems like a problem with the other end, or a bug in ssh.net, maybe you should make a git hub issue https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues

Comment: So the problem has nothing to do with a file upload, but with a connection to the SFTP server, right? + Did you check server-side log file?

Comment: I dont have access to the server. The file uploads very few times its like 1 in every 100 attempts. I am using Using SSH.NET 2016.1.0